# vehicle.stop is not a function p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm beginning to learn p5.js, and to help me learn I have started creating a "driving game". It's not even close to being done, but I have run into an error saying

> vehicle.stop is not a function.

The point of the game is to have the user press the up arrow to "drive" the car even though there is no movement that happens when it is pressed. The user has 60 seconds total to play, but at certain times in the game a stop sign will appear and the user must then hit the spacebar as fast as they can. If the spacebar is pressed within 1 second of the sign appearing then the user gets the point. I am unsure as to why I am getting the error message, and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated! :)

```
var count = 6;
let timer = 60;
var score = 0;

function preload() {

  car = loadImage('car.png');
  stop = loadImage('stop.png');

}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  background(100, 200, 255);

  stroke(150);
  strokeWeight(120);
  line(1000, -2000, 10, 400);

  line(600, 1000, 250, 20);

  strokeWeight(250);
  line(200, 600, 200, 200);

  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(255);
  line(210, 100, 210, 10);

  line(210, 300, 210, 150);

  image(car, 110, 220);


}

function draw() {

  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(200);
  fill(0);
  text("Score: " + score, 20, 30);
  text("Time Left: " + timer, 20, 45);

  if ((frameCount % 120 == 0) && (timer > 0)) {
    timer--;
  }

  if ((timer == 60) || (score == 0)) {
    fill(0);
    rect(115, 225, 200, 70);
    fill(255);
    text("START DRIVING GAME ", 142, 250);
    text("CLICK BUTTON TO BEGIN", 135, 265);
    text("USE UP-ARROW KEY TO DRIVE", 130, 280);
  }

  if ((timer == 0) || (score == count)) {
    fill(0);
    rect(130, 220, 125, 70);
    fill(255);
    text("GAME OVER", 150, 250);
    text("You scored: " + score, 150, 265);
  }


}

function mouseClicked() {
  vehicle.stop();

}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == UP_ARROW) {
    car.go();
  } else if (keyCode == 32) {
    car.stop();
  }
}

function vehicle() {

  this.go = function() {
    goTime = new Date();

  }

  this.stop = function() {

    if ((timer == 55) || (timer == 40) || (timer == 32) || (timer == 23) ||
      (timer == 15) || (timer == 6)) {

      image(stop, 170, 90);

    }
    stopTime = new Date();
    if ((vehicle.stop) && (elapsedTime == 1)) {
      score = score + 1;
    } else(score = score + 0);

  }

  elapsedTime = goTime - stopTime;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey :) Rabbid76 pointed out there are additional errors in the code.

The reason vehicle.stop is not found is because 'constructor functions' like the vehicle function you wrote, need to be defined using the 'new' keyword.

```
let myVehicle = new vehicle();

myVehicle.stop() //should work, once you fix the additional errors.
```

There is some good information about this in this page:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp

I always prefer using classes. 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp

Comment: Ohh okay! Thank you so much!!